# Spotfire Calculate date difference based on match

Tags: date, spotfire

I'm having some struggle with calculating dates. Let's imagine a dataset of multiple patients (over thousands), I will present just a single one, as a column [patient_ID]. Keep in mind logic of Intersect/Over for this scenario.
For this patient, I need to calculate time between two events, based on matching on column in between (match_key). For instance, when match is 2234, take Date 2 at that match then deduct same match key on Date 1. Here is an example of desired output:

```
patient_ID   match_key    Date1                 Date2               Desired_column
patient5       2234      21/10/2023 14:34    21/10/2023 14:36  21/10/2023 14:55 - 21/10/2023 14:34
patient5       7889      21/10/2023 14:34    21/10/2023 14:38  21/10/2023 15:45 - 21/10/2023 14:34
patient5                 21/10/2023 16:17    21/10/2023 14:40
patient5       2234      21/10/2023 14:34    21/10/2023 14:55
patient5                 21/10/2023 16:45    21/10/2023 15:36
patient5       7889      21/10/2023 17:03    21/10/2023 15:45
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a way to add the column to every row that has a non-null match key:

```
(If([match_key] is not null,Max([Date2]) over ([patient_ID], 
[match_key]),null)) - (If([match_key] is not null,Min([Date1]) over 
([patient_ID],[match_key]),null))
```

where the first part:

```
(If([match_key] is not null,Max([Date2]) over ([patient_ID], 
[match_key]),null))
```

calculates the maximum Date2 for the patient and match_key, and the second part:

```
(If([match_key] is not null,Min([Date1]) over 
([patient_ID],[match_key]),null))
```

returns the minimum Date2 for the patient and match_key.

I cannot see a way of only returning it for the first row of each match key, at least not in one go. Is that part of the requirement?